# In Java/Spring Boot/JPA/Hibernate, is there a simple mechanism to track entity changes to generate a change report?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

We process a spreadsheet that comes from our contractor tracking inventory.

Using Apache POI and oCell to read the Excel file using a POJO (not our InventoryItem entity) then validating and parsing the data into an InventoryItem entity.

During processing, we note new records and insert them in our DB. For pre-existing records, we don't do any change detection, but simply update all fields in the record.

We'd like a "mini audit" mechanism to where we can note expected changes (say, reductions in inventory) versus corrections (say, names of product, supplier, or some other change).

While we could, during the conversion/mapping from ExcelInventoryItem into InventoryItem, check each field for value change, but that would be manual (prone to error) and tedious.

Is there a simple mechanism to capture which fields have changed so that we can capture that information and provide a per-file report back to the user upon completion of processing?

I briefly looked at what JPA auditing does based on [what I found at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa), but it looks like a bit of overkill for what I want (accumulate a list of changes, JSON-ify it and shove it into an already available "concerns" field.) Also, it doesn't appear to track specific field changes (before/after) without iterating over fields myself.

Any recommendations for a good strategy?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should go with **Hibernate Envers**, it's not an overkill. You can configure **Envers** to audit only what you need and they provide a very nice API to query the audited entities.